# Flickering Video on Safari Browser

Tags: html, video, safari

I have been developing a website for a client this past week and he tells me the site works fine on chrome but not on safari. 
Unfortunatly I do not have an apple device but the site works fine on all the browsers my end!
Here is a video showing how it looks on Safari:

https://a.uguu.se/l0yAhSOlet1C.mp4

Not sure what more I can do to it but I'm pretty sure it's not my code!
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Phillip Dews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem is definitely not in your code, it is a know issue I quickly searched on Google and I found that there are quite a bit of people that experience this issue I think probably because they are running an older version of Mac OS.

Here are some useful links you can read and inform your client:
A lot of people have similar flickering patterns.

- [Link 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4494697?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Link 2](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/screen-flicker-safari-issue.441340/)
- [Link 3](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/2g785wSOW-0;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/category$3Aplaying-and-watching-videos)

Comment: Thank you Sem, I have passed this onto my client!